Selenium in Ubuntu 22.04 - Exception-SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Message: Session not created
I am pretty new to Selenium and have been trying to setup selenium in my ubuntu 22.04.
chrome version and location, chromedriver version and java version.

Basic sample of the code I am trying to run.


Tried checking the google-chrome and chromedriver compatibility - It is same
Have given the executable permission to chromedriver
Tried uninstalling google-chrome and chromedriver and installing it again from the first
Tried uninstalling eclipse and installing it again
Tried with geckodriver as well, but did not succeed and would like to do with chromedriver itself.

Unable to proceed.

is the chromedriver binary available in the PATH? Like, can run it from any directory?
Maybe post an image running which chromedriver too?

which chromedriver
/usr/bin/chromedriver
This is what i get for which chromedriver

it's sort of strange that your versions of browser and driver match exactly.  (Usually they're a little off...  only major versions need to match).  I would re-download chromedriver from here: https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable  You can also skip setting system property and Selenium's built-in manager should download latest versions of browser/driver.

I had downloaded chrome from the said link. Prolly thats why the versions are exact. And do I need to install selenium webdriver manager to skip setting system property?

Prolly Looks (to me) like your comment contains Newspeak :-)

You can also check the Chrome application version from browser settings (Settings > Help > About Google Chrome) and download the chrome driver from this link: https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/
OR
As you're using selenium version greater than 3 (ie. 4.17.0) so there is no need to set the property.
Just use following code to open the chome browser:
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com");


It still does not work, I get the same error. :(
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.   (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)   (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
